# edit and continue on visual studio 2010 express for windows phone 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I enabled edit and continue, but when i'm running the simulator, it tells me that `changes are not allowed to code running on the .net compact framework`

I just want to edit my code for the next build, without having to leave debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no editing of code while it's running in this environment.

You'll need to end your debug session, change your code, and run.

Comment: wow ! I'm new to Windows development, but isn't that a problem ?! I used XCode and Eclipse without issues... Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: I've used it occasionally, but I can't say I really miss it. Different people may work different ways though. I've worked with a lot of debuggers, editors and IDEs over the years.. it's honestly never been hard to find a groove that works given available tooling, even with the most rudimentary of tools. IDEs and debuggers the likes of Borland and Visual Studio kick ass in so many respects I've always found myself feeling thankful for good tools. Can you believe some people laugh at what you can do nowadays coming from times when you had to try and right your code to work first time.